# How to obtain a char's ascii value in haskell? And how to turn an ascii value (65, let's say) into a char (A)?

Tags: haskell, char, int

How to accomplish that in Haskell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hoogle is your friend:

http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int

```
import Data.Char   
ord 'a'
chr 98
```

Comment: No. But from now on, you are.

Comment: @devoured elysium - You might consider accepting your new friend's answer then. :-)

Comment: Also `fromEnum`/`toEnum`: `fromEnum 'a' == 97`, `(toEnum 97 :: Char) == 'a'`.

Comment: I prefer just using `fromEnum`/`toEnum`. Less to remember, since they work for more types :)

Comment: I was hoogling and hacking the crap out of this and got lead down a lot of encoding and ascii byte code rabbit holes before I decided to google not Hoogle…